# How the RatingBar styling works in lists

Tags: android, styling, ratingbar

I have troubles understanding how the styling of RatingBar in Android works. I am using the very same styled RatingBar in two different layouts and getting a different output.

Rating bar in a element that is part of list view:

```
<RatingBar
  android:isIndicator="true"
  android:id="@+id/itemRatingBar"
  style="?android:attr/ratingBarStyleSmall"
  android:layout_width="wrap_content"
  android:layout_height="wrap_content"
  android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
  android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
  android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
  android:numStars="5"
  android:rating="1.5" />
```

Result: https://i.stack.imgur.com/gF5aQ.png

Rating bar on another activity, not part of list view:

```
<RatingBar
  android:isIndicator="true"
  android:id="@+id/itemRatingBar"
  style="?android:attr/ratingBarStyleSmall"
  android:layout_width="wrap_content"
  android:layout_height="wrap_content"
  android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
  android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
  android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
  android:numStars="5"
  android:rating="1.5" />
```

Result: https://i.stack.imgur.com/n5nY7.png

As you ca see at the end I ended up with literally same specification of rating bar, yet the result is different on my Samsung S5 in two different activities.

I would be quite OK with the changed tint/color, the size of the stars bothers me most. Just for your information, the container the RatingBar is in and the surrounding elements are also the same.

Thanks for the help